# Pushing out hosts to /etc/hosts ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to setup an application which requires entries into /etc/hosts for all servers in the cluster. I'm trying to figure out an easy way to push all hosts to all /etc/hosts files on each server. I tried this but got an error back saying permission denied.

```
for i in `cat servers`; do cat additional.hosts | ssh -T username@$i "sudo cat >> /etc/hosts";done
```

Of course the additional.hosts file is sitting on my local computer and needs to go to the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi clogan1981. I edited the question to hopefully represent your snippet correctly. Please check to make sure that such is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
for i in `cat servers`; do cat additional.hosts | ssh -T username@$i "sudo bash -c 'cat >> /etc/hosts'";done
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.